# Find the title of the show or movie with the shortest run-time in R

Tags: r

Hi guys how can I find the title of the show or movie with the shortest runtime in a given dataset. I have tried **min(titles$runtime)** but that only returns the minimum runtime not the title(which is inside the title heading) of the movie or show which are part of part of the "types" heading

Comment: It's hard to say without a snippet of your data but `which.min()` returns the index where the minimum is located. You can then use that to access the row (I'm asumming) where the title is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that code

```
titles[which.min(titles$runtime),]
```

To find out which row has the shortest run time.

From your code I assume that titles is the name of your dataframe.
It is always dataframe and then columnname

```
df[which.min(df$colname),]
```

for more explanation see this website
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-extract-the-dataframe-row-with-min-or-max-values-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on toy data:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  title = c("X", "Y", "Z"),
  runtime = c(12.5,13.7,10)
)
```

Solution in `base R` to obtain just the `title` value:

```
df$title[df$runtime == min(df$runtime)]
[1] "Z"
```

To obtain the **row** with the value in question:

```
df[df$runtime == min(df$runtime),]
  title runtime
3     Z      10
```

Solution in `tidyverse` to get the entire row:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  filter(runtime == min(runtime))
```

To get just the `title` value:

```
df %>%
  filter(runtime == min(runtime)) %>%
  pull(title)
```